# How to make TypeScript acceppt setState callback in React Hooks?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, callback, setstate

everyone! I'm trying to define my component types using TypeScript and I want to make it so that I can pass either an array of objects or the callback function containing the previous state. This is my code:

```
type ChipsContextData = {
    chips: Array<ChipsData>,
    setChips: (newChips: Array<ChipsData>) => void | ((setCallback: (previousState: ChipsData[]) => ChipsData[]) => void); 
    counters: Array<number>;
    setCounters: (newCounters: Array<number>) => void; 
}
```

But TypeScript won't let me use the second part of the union. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly wrap(with braces) each type in union, like this:

```
type ChipsContextData = {
  chips: Array<ChipsData>;
  setChips:
    | ((newChips: Array<ChipsData>) => void)
    | ((setCallback: (previousState: ChipsData[]) => ChipsData[]) => void);
  counters: Array<number>;
  setCounters: (newCounters: Array<number>) => void;
};
```

**UPDATED**

But if you want `either an array of objects or the callback function containing the previous state` as you said in OP, which is by the way completely different from what you did, then do like this:

```
type ChipsContextData = {
  chips: Array<ChipsData>;
  setChips:
    | Array<ChipsData>
    | (previousState: ChipsData[]) => ChipsData[];
  counters: Array<number>;
  setCounters: (newCounters: Array<number>) => void;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work :(

Comment: Well, I am not sure which type you want, but like this you declare two optional types: first one is function that accepts array of ChipsData elements as argument, and returns nothing(void), and second one is function that accepts another function(which accepts array of ChipsData elements as argument and returns array of ChipsData elements) as argument and returns nothing(also void). Does this makes sense to you, you wanted type like those two I just described?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly that!

Comment: If still not fixed, then please update OP with the example of code that is not working, and with complete typescript error message.

Answer (score 0):

If `chips`, `setChips`, `counters` and `setCounters` are regular states/setStates created using something like this:

```
const [chips, setChips] = useState<ChipsData[]>([])
const [counter, setCounter] = useState<number>(0)
```

then, you can create your `ChipsContextData` type like below, which is the type of React's setState action:

```
type ChipsContextData = {
  chips: Array<ChipsData>
  setChips: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Array<ChipsData>>>
  counters: Array<number>
  setCounters: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
}
```